# Should one list only electives or major courses on linkedin?

Tags: linkedin

If one majors in Finance and minor in IT should they list only electives under courses section? Or should they include all courses taken in that post graduate program?

Answer (score 2):

Listing **only a few** courses seems to be the norm on LinkedIn.  **Choose a handful of courses that you are excited to share and you feel demonstrate your capabilities.**

Your **electives** are likely better to include in this section because they are more likely to:

1. Demonstrate *distinctive* interests or capabilities
2. Demonstrate achievement beyond the requirement curriculum (e.g., if you took a graduate-level course in an undergraduate program)
3. Be more closely aligned to your professional interests, and thus attract opportunities you will have great interest in

This, of course, isn't a hard and fast rule - pick the courses that make the most sense to you.